# How to setup backstrech on rails

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am trying to set up [backstrech](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/) on my Rails app. I have a functioning website but I want a nice back ground. I followed [these directions](https://github.com/socialreferral/backstretch-rails)

I have installed the backstrech gem by adding `gem 'backstretch-rails'` to my Gemfile.

I then did a bundle install and added `//= require 'jquery.backstretch'` to my /app/assets/javascripts/application.js file.
It looks like:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require 'jquery.backstretch'
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

I am at a loss on where to put `$.backstretch("/path/to/image.jpg", {speed: 150});`

I tried to put the following on both the page I am currently on and just in the /views/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
%script
  $.backstretch("/path/to/image.jpg", {speed: 150});
```

Neither of these have worked for me.

Please let me know what I should do. As of right now I am just not getting any background at all.

Comment: Did you restart the server? Are you getting any javascript error?

Comment: `%script` looks like haml, you said your page was erb?

Comment: Sorry using both erb and haml. Using html.erb if it was generated and I haven't really edited the file such as the application.html.erb and .html.haml if it's a view that I'm using a lot. But I do change the code accordingly based on it being haml or html